# jquery ajax variable value set to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, python, jquery, ajax

I parsed json with  ajax. And I want to show that parsed value on same page. So that value set to php variable. And that php variable  parse with using python. Also I don't want to parse with using php or python. Because, ajax parse process faster than php or python parse process. I did something like that:

#### sample.php

---

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['data'])){
    echo $_GET['data'];
}
else {

    ?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/', // example json
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      var json_result = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log(json_result); // The whole JSON
      window.location.href = "http://localhost/jsn/sample.php/?data="+data;
    }
  });
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

---

#### dene.py

```
import requests
import pycurl
import urllib.request

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://localhost/jsn/sample.php/')
# Follow redirect.
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

---

I can show  data parsed by ajax. But  I couldn't get value that data with python. How can I resolve that problem.

Comment: AJAX doesn't parse anything so how it can do it faster than any of the languages tagged is beyond me. At a best guess, you're referring to JQuery

Comment: ajax is async your python curl is no javascript interpreter. why dont you call the endpoint with python or php. why you mix php and python they are both backend interpreter languages. You cant access javascript client side data. (atleast not that easy)

Comment: and btw.: echo $_GET['data']; is vulnerable to crossside scripting attacks. you shouldnt echo user input unfiltered

Comment: yes, I'm talking about jquery.

Comment: how can ı show data which parsed by jquery on same page for parse with python.

Comment: yoz shouldnt do it. yiur setup is wrong. either parse the url from the page and make the call with python. only solution without implementing a whole browser is selenium webdriver: https://www.seleniumhq.org/. v8 could do the job as well but its overkill you shouldnt use javascript https://v8.dev/